# Overloading new and delete in array

Tags: c++

I am writing a program for overloading new and delete in Arrays in c++.Here is the code

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

class loc {
  int longitude, latitude;
public:
  loc() {longitude = latitude = 0;}
  loc(int lg, int lt) {
    longitude = lg;
    latitude = lt;
  }

  void show() {
    cout << longitude << " ";
    cout << latitude << "\n";
  }

  void *operator new(size_t size);
  void operator delete(void *p);

  void *operator new[](size_t size);
  void operator delete[](void *p);
};

// new overloaded relative to loc.
void *loc::operator new(size_t size)
{
void *p;

  cout << "In overloaded new.\n";
  p =  malloc(size);
  if(!p) {
    bad_alloc ba;
    throw ba;
  }
  return p;
}

// delete overloaded relative to loc.
void loc::operator delete(void *p)
{
  cout << "In overloaded delete.\n";
  free(p);
}

// new overloaded for loc arrays.
void *loc::operator new[](size_t size)
{
  void *p;

  cout << "Using overload new[].\n";
  p =  malloc(size);
  if(!p) {
    bad_alloc ba;
    throw ba;
  }
  return p;
}

// delete overloaded for loc arrays
void loc::operator delete[](void *p)
{
  cout << "Freeing array using overloaded delete[]\n";
  free(p);
}

int main()
{
  loc *p1, *p2;
  int i;

  try {
    p1 = new loc (10, 20); // allocate an object
  } catch (bad_alloc xa) {
    cout << "Allocation error for p1.\n";
    return 1;;
  }

  try {
    p2 = new loc [10]; // allocate an array
  } catch (bad_alloc xa) {
    cout << "Allocation error for p2.\n";
    return 1;;
  }

  p1->show();

  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    p2[i].show();

  delete p1; // free an object
  delete [] p2; // free an array

  return 0;
}
```

In the line  `p2[i].show();` in the main.Why we are we using **"."**. instead of **"->"** .Is the answer is that it became array?is it true.
 **can we make pointer say p3 to the pointer p2?**
like  declaring

```
loc *p1,*p2,**p3;
p3=&p2;
```

but then how we will display the result through p3.should we display like `p3[i]->show()`
When I tired the program hanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. An array is a sequence of identically typed objects stored one after the other. A pointer in an "address of an object".

The coincidence you observe is the consequence of two fact:

- An array decays into a "pointer to the first element" when given to functions, and ...
- The pseudo `T& operator[](T* p, int i)` is implemented intrinsically by the compiler as `return *(p+i);`

As a consequence wherever you store a sequence of identical objects, and you have a starting address, the [] operator will lead you to the i-th object. And since the starting address of an array is the address of the first element and is obtained by the implicit array to pointer conversion, you observe a substantial coincidence of the two expression.

But the coincidence stops just there.

About pointing to a pointer, make sure you fully understand the concept: by the way you asked it is not clear if:

- you want another pointer to point to the same array (just assign the array address to another pointer or the first pointer to another one
- you want a pointer to point to the pointer that points to the array: this is a double indirection. You need a "pointer to pointer" and assign it to it the address of the first pointer (not of the array)

Jut to be more clear:

```
int a[5] = { 10,11,12,13,14 }; //5 integer named "a"
int* p = a; // p points to a[0], hence *p and p[0] gives 10, p[1] give 11
int* q = p+1; // q points to one after p (hence to 11), *q and q[0] are 11, q[1] 12 ...
int** d = &p; // d points to p, hence **d is 10 (*d)[1] 11 etc.
```

The hang you observed is due to the fact `d[3]` is not the integer 13, but the third `int*` after `p` (what `d` points to). But being `p` just a single variable, there is not such object, hence the result is undefined. (You had been lucky it hanged: in the worst case you get a random result that can be even look correct, thus hiding the error!).

In your specific case, `p3[i]->show` takes the value incidentally stored in the memory `i` pointers  after `p2` (what p3 points to) treat it as a `pointer to loc` and try to execute the `show` method of the supposed `loc` object at that random address, most likely not belonging to your program memory space, so that `show` fails to access the `longitude` local variable.

The result -substantially- all depends on the random data present in p3[i].

Comment: But when we write (*p3)[i].show() then we are doing casting .How is different from p3[i].show()?Means it donot access p3+i?

Comment: (*p3)[i] is not casting. Casting is when between the () there is a type name, not an expression. the () here are just to force precedence to * before to []. Note also that p3+i is not p3[i]. p3[i] is *(p3+i)

Comment: In case this may help you, (*p3)[i] can also viewed as p3[0][i], where p3[0] is actually p2.  But p3[1] (or whatever other number) is undefined being p2 a single variable.

Answer (score 1):

> should we display like `p3[i]->show()`?

No. In this line you're trying to access `p3 + i` memory address. This causes Undefined Behavior. You should use

```
(*p3)[i].show()
```

You should use `p3[i]->show()` in case if `p3[i]` holds pointer.

Comment: Say, you have a class `Foo` with `some_method`. You declare an array of pointers to `Foo`: `Foo* arr[10];`. Then, if you want to call  `some_method` you should use `arr[i]->some_method();`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why we are we using ".". instead of "->" ? Is the answer is that it became array?

Because p2[i] is actually an instance of loc instead of a pointer to loc; `"loc *p2"` p2 is a pointer to loc, not an array, and it won't become an array.

> can we make pointer say p3 to the pointer p2?

Yes, It is legal. But make p2 is initialized first (instead of being a dangling pointer) in your real world project.